# On initializing length of array in C++

Tags: c++

I notice people write:

```
int array[N];
```

to initialize an array without specifying the value of `N`. Can I ask what does `N` means here? Is it `INT_MAX`?

Comment: "*..to initialize an array without specifying the value of N"*, are you sure about that?

Comment: Do you notice their code doesn't compile?

Comment: No, they don't. I think you've misread something.

Comment: `N` is not defined in standard  C++, but its a common substitute for the word count in math and code examples.

Comment: Remember, in C++ the `N` needs to be a compile time constant or a macro (which defines a constant).  Variable length arrays are not supported.

Comment: Read variable length arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's just constant N, defined somewhere above.
`const size_t N = 10`
or 
`#define N 10`

Comment: Can't be a variable in standard C++. It has to be a compile time constant.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, thanks, I changed answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

There are only three possibilities:

1. `N` was earlier defined as a `constexpr` or a `const` value (this includes a literal value).
2. `N` is a macro previously `#define`-d, perhaps in some header file
3. A non-standard C++ compiler extension is being used, that allows a variable-length array to be specified using a non-constant value.

To figure out which is the case, you'll need to search back in the source wherever `N` is defined. It has to be defined somewhere, otherwise this will not compile.

Comment: Theoretically, as a 4th option, `N` could be defined through as command line argument when calling the compiler. Then it won't shine up in any source file.